# Donation in Windows Phone application

Tags: api, windows-phone, payment, donations

I have an application for windows phone and its free. I want it to stay free and without ads. But sometimes i need motivation. What i need to do is to add some "buy a pint of beer to the author" button in my application (something like donation button). Sure i can create 2 versions: paid and free that are completely identical in functions just the paid with some "thanks" words, but that will be 2 completely different applications and i'll need to support them both. So..Is it possible to implement some donation payment in the application?

Comment: On WP8 you can use in-app purchases for that. On WP7, there's no built-in mechanism. You could put a paypal link or something, but I wouldn't be surprised if it violated the marketplace rules.

Comment: @KooKiz just WP8 is ok, but as i saw you need to provide list of inapp purchase items and their descriptions.. What should i do in case of "pay if you want" case?!

Comment: "Unlocks developer gratitude" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an in-app purchase would be your best route.  Here's the MSDN article describing the in-app mechanism.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: is there any way to make a "pay WHAT you want" in-app purchase? I can only see instructions to set specific prices for each add-in.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is use trial API.

Trial licenses don't expire. It's up to you to define the differences between trial and non-trial modes.

In the marketplace description, you can write that trial and full modes are identical. And, in the about page inside your app, place either "if you like it buy it" button that opens a marketplace task, or big "thanks for your support!" textblock.